# Will I be able to see a light coming from a laser in the edge of the universe?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, photons, intensity

It is said that light's intensity decreases with increase in distance. Suppose if there is a laser in complete vacuum, emitting a collimated light beam from one end of the universe for about 93 billion light years (assuming the universe stopped expanding by now). I am at the other end of the universe and facing exactly towards the laser. No stars and absolutely no light emitting source other than laser and no celestial bodies other that me. Now, the photons from the laser must reach some point. In this case, no factors are affecting the photons, will it reach my eyes with the same intensity it had at the time the photons started its journey? Is there any factors that will change the light's intensity?

Comment: The universe has no edge.

Comment: @Ishwaran that is irrelevant. The universe has no edge regardless of whether it is expanding or not.

Comment: Are you assuming that the laser beam won't spread out?

Comment: How do you make the light beams exactly parallel? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_beam

Comment: @Ishwaran Do note that it is impossible to construct a laser with zero beam divergence, even in theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you have a source that emits photons along a single line *and* an observer/measurement device that lies on that line *and* these are the only objects in the universe *and* space is not expanding then each photon emitted by the source will reach the observer and will have the same energy as when it was emitted, so the intensity of the light beam will not change with distance.

But that seems like a very artificial/theoretical scenario.

Comment: @Ishwaran So the only conclusion here seems to be that if you completely remove all the interactions that could change a photon's wavelength or direction then its wavelength and direction do not change.